# Is there a way to use one [SetUpFixture] in multiple projects/assemblies?

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I am trying to create a **SetUpFixture** class that runs a **OneTimeSetup** in which I instantiate multiple other entities from other assemblies (a logger, a DB provider, etc.) and I want to use this OneTimeSetup every time I start a new test suite.

My tests are scattered across multiple assemblies as well, with their own base **setUp** and **tearDown**,
but they have common attribute tags which I want to use in order to trigger my run.

Is there a way to specify my SetUpFixture for the whole test run, regardless of where the tests are coming from, so I can just run all the tests with a specific Attribute tag?
Or is there a way that I can use a "run id" and pass it from one assembly to another?

Comment: The way we did this is to create a separate class with [SetupFixture] and and a [OneTimeSetup] method, and link this class into all other test projects (in Visual Studio, "Add file as link")

Comment: Any success? I would write an answer if yes

Comment: No, it seems that NUnit is not picking up the code in the [OneTimeSetup]. It just runs as if the class didn't exist. Did you use a specific Namespace for the linked classes?

Comment: Correction: I managed to link it properly and it somehow works, but not as intended. Correct me if i'm wrong but the linked class is instantiated once for each project, and unfortunately that causes a few issues.
You see, i have a report manager(Extent reports) that generates reports based on test runs, and I initialize this report manager inside the [OneTimeSetup] so that I can have one report for all tests, regardless of the assembly that they're in, but currently the linked class creates 1 report for each assembly, it doesn't re-use one.

Comment: Ah, that might be. We primarily used it to reduce duplicate initialization for multiple test assemblies and don't need a single instance of something per session. Apparently [SetupFixture] runs once for the tests in its namespace, maybe it's possible to put in a "top" namespace such as "MyCompany", if all other tests are under "MyCompany.Product1.Tests", "MyCompany.Product2.Tests" etc?